# compile code with large arrays in gfortran or ifortran

Tags: arrays, compilation, fortran

I have a fortran code where I have to declare an array with 600000 elements.

In order to compile the code with gfortran I use the flag `-fmax-array-constructor=600000`.

However, the same flag doesn't work when switching to ifortran. Do you know what flag I should use instead?

Comment: `-heap-arrays` might help.  The issues are how the arrays are stored in memory, stack or otherwise.

Comment: I think you should put some code, at least show how you declared the array, e.g. is it automatic or not? Also, maybe explain why the allocatable array presented in the answers is not an option?

Comment: I fear some code should be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try making the array allocatable:

```
 real,allocatable::a(:)
 allocate(a(600000))
```

Comment: thanks! but the problem is that I would like to avoid reading the elements of `a`, for example, from an external file. I am using a parallel code and I'm declaring the large array in a module. If I were to declare the array as allocatable, then read it on any core, that would be impractical.

Comment: There is a typo in the declaration above (need an "a") but the site won't let make "trivial" edits.

Comment: typo fixed, thanks. @Matteo if your problem is more complicated edit the question to explain it.. (I don't see what reading from files has to do with anything..?)

Comment: my problem is much bigger than what I've described in the question. It can easily be solved if the array is declared as allocatable, but I wish I could avoid that. My original question is how come I can declare a 640000-element array in gfortran but not with ifort?

Comment: I find that the only solution is to allocate the array and then read it from an external file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the "large" arrays flags in the compilation:

```
gfortran -O3 -mcmodel=medium -o executable your.source.f90
```

the `-mcmodel=medium` flag allows to allocate arrays larger than 10^9 points.

Comment: Note that the asker is asking for an ifort flag, although this particular flag is the same for both. We have some questions about this flag.